# Enabling `overflow: scroll` for a parent object makes a scrollable child object unreachable

Tags: javascript, css, handsontable

In Handsontable, there is a DropDownMenu object. I've managed to decrease its height and add the CSS-property `overflow: scroll`. Also, there is a child object CheckboxList (CheckBoxRenderer) inside it, which is also scrollable (using the same property `overflow: scroll`).

The problem is, when I make DropDownMenu (parent) scrollable, I cannot reach the CheckboxList (child) - I can't neither click a checkbox, nor scroll the child object.

Is there any way to add some property like `: focus` or `: active` to reach the child object?

Alright, here is the catch:

This is a child object

```
.htDropdownMenu .ht_master .wtHolder {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

This is a parent:

```
.htDropdownMenu .ht_master .wtHider {
  overflow: hidden;
  width : 130px !important;
}
```

Now, everything is OK - child object is scrollable and runs through all existing rows in the list properly, as well as clickable, too.

Let's change them a bit. I want do make a parent object smaller, so I add height into the class style. Because of this, some objects get hidden due to an overflow, so I add a scroll and here's the result:

```
.htDropdownMenu .ht_master .wtHider {
  overflow: scroll;
  width : 130px !important;
  height: 130px !important;
}
```

This results in parent object become scrollable, but the child is not scrolling (despite it has a `overflow: scroll` property)

Comment: Could you please share an example code, that we could understand better what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @UmurDinçer I've updated the question for it. Feel free to ask if you need some additional info.